# Autorestart if service stops SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2014-express

I've just installed SQL Server 2014 Express, last night the service stopped and didn't restart.
Searching online I found only the option on SQL Server Agent to auto restart if the service stops, which is not available on SQL Server Express edition.

Is there any way to set up autorestart if service fails or stops?

I'm on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server.

Comment: Have you set any [Recovery Actions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753662.aspx) for the SQL Server service when it stops?

Comment: i've done now, thanks!

Comment: it didn't restart the service immediately(it took like 10 hours), is there any way to make it restart immediately?
also i have this problem that is stopping the server
SQL Server is terminating because of fatal exception c0000006. This error may be caused by an unhandled Win32 or C++ exception<c/> or by an access violation encountered during exception handling. Check the SQL error log for any related stack dumps or messages. This exception forces SQL Server to shutdown. To recover from this error<c/> restart the server (unless SQLAgent is configured to auto restart).

Answer (score -1):

Please do a scheduled task that run a script like that;

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "mssql" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   net start "mssql"
  )
)
```

Please just validate the servicename for your sql instance.